# SMTP-server npm does not receive the mail data

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, smtp, postfix-mta

I have been looking during hours for an answer to my question. I think this question ([Send email to localhost smtp server in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966835/send-email-to-localhost-smtp-server-in-node-js)) is quite the same but the answer didn't help me.

So I have two VM's which run on Centos7. And I want my VM 1 to send an email to my VM 2. Here is what I have done :

VM 1 : Postfix is installed and configured with it :  relayhost = [ip of vm 2]:25

VM 2 : The port 25 is opened. There is the code which listen in port 25 :

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs-extra') 
const SMTPServer = require('smtp-server').SMTPServer
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser
const date = require('date-and-time')
const builder = require('xmlbuilder') //9.0.4

const say = msg => {
            console.log(msg)
}


const server = new SMTPServer({
  logger: true,
  //secure: true,
  //authOptional: true,
  //disabledCommands: ['AUTH'],
  disabledCommands: ['AUTH', 'STARTTLS'],

  // By default only PLAIN and LOGIN are enabled
  authMethods: ['PLAIN', 'LOGIN', 'CRAM-MD5'],

  onConnect: function(session, callback){
    say('hello')
    callback()
  },
  onData: function(stream, session, callback) {
    say('received');
    callback()
  },

 })


server.on('error', err => {
  say('Error %s', err.message)
})

server.listen(25)
```

**From VM 2 :** When I send a mail to locahost with sendmail :

```
sendmail ldecaudin@localhost < email.txt
```

, I can see the **"hello"** and the **"received"**

**From VM 1 :** When I send a mail with sendmail (which is automatically relayed by postfix to my VM2) using it :

```
sendmail ldecaudin@[192.168.56.101] < email.txt
```

I can only see the **"hello"**, so the connection is running, but I am not able to pass in the **"onData"** function to get the stream I need.

Also from my VM1, I have a node code which send mails using nodemailer, this code works. When I use this code, I have the same result ("hello" but not "received"), but there are 2 connections instead of one.

So I am totally lost, I tried to add the "onAuth" function, to try many options of "new SMTPServer".

I wonder if this is a problem with a port (but port 25 is open!), or maybe I forgot to put something on Postfix. I don't know.

Can you help me please ?

Thank you a lot by advance !

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I will be glad to hear it as I'm running on the same problem :)

Comment: No, I have never found, sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to answer but I faced a similar issue a couple of hours ago writing this answer. Answering in a hope that somebody will find it helpful in the future...

As per the SMTP standards, it sends `mailform`, `rcptto` commands before actually sending the body.. and hence, here in this nodeJs lib, the handler methods equivalent to those commands `mailfrom` -> `onMailFrom(...)` & `rcptto` -> `onRcptTo(...)` is getting called and ARE EXPECTED TO CALL `callback()` in order to send success signal on the connected SMTP socket.

In my case, I wrote an empty handler and was not calling the `callback` on `onMailFrom` & `onRcptTo`. This was creating the problem.

Calling the callbacks from the above handlers fixed it.

Code sample when I faced the issue:

```
.
.
.
onMailFrom: (address, session, callback) => {},
onRcptTo: (address, session, callback) => {},
.
.
```

Code sample when I called `callback`:

```
.
.
.
onMailFrom: (address, session, callback) => {
    return callback();
},
onRcptTo: (address, session, callback) => {
    return callback();
},
.
.
.
```

Adding a note: Do check on other handler functions as well, if this solution doesn't work. Debugging helped me here to identify the problem in my case.